# is there any way for algolia api to get record through objectID and update that record

Tags: php, algolia

hey i am just asking about Algolia API (search engine) once i stored record into indices then how an i update that

```php
// composer autoload
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// if you are not using composer
// require_once 'path/to/algolia/folder/autoload.php';
$client = Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\SearchClient::create(
    'myapplicationid',
    'myadminid'
);
$index = $client->initIndex('testing');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=test", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$users = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$objects = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $objects[] = [
        'objectID' => $user['user_id'],
        'user_id' => $user['user_id'],
        'first_name' => $user['user_first_name'],
        'last_name' => $user['user_last_name'],
        'contact_number' => $user['user_contact'],
    ];
}
$index->saveObjects($objects);
```

when i am looping record how can i add condition to get record through objectID from algolia if the record exist then update otherwise add record into Algolia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use partialUpdateObjects and set 'createIfNotExists' => true
doc is here, https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/partial-update-objects/

Comment: i need to get single record from my indices like if(myalgoliarecord == mydatabase) { update } else { insert}

Comment: Example,
`$objects[] = [
        'objectID' => $user['user_id'],
        'user_id' => $user['user_id'],
        'first_name' => $user['user_first_name'],
        'last_name' => $user['user_last_name'],
        'contact_number' => $user['user_contact'],
    ];     
    
    
 try {     
  /*createIfNotExists - will create a record if not exist (insert) otherwise existing record update matching with your objectID (update)*/
   if($this->index != null) {
    $this->index->partialUpdateObjects(
      $objects,
      ['createIfNotExists' => true ]
      );
     } 
    }`

Comment: in document we have update and create but where is the condition to check that the database record exist with algolia record

Comment: createIfNotExists - will create a record if not exist in Algolia (insert) otherwise existing record update matching with your objectID (update in your case). You have to gather your data, send it to this function and it will take care of it

Comment: `
$objects[] = [
   'objectID' => $user['user_id'],
   'user_id' => $user['user_id'],
   'first_name' => $user['user_first_name'],
   'last_name' => $user['user_last_name'],
   'contact_number' => $user['user_contact'],
  ];
                 
try {     

  /*createIfNotExists - will create a record if not exist (insert) otherwise existing record update matching with your objectID (update)*/    
  if($index != null) {
  $index->partialUpdateObjects(
   $objects[],
    ['createIfNotExists' => true ]
   );
 } 
}
`

Comment: work perfect as expected thank you very much but the condition you specified isn't work $index->partialUpdateObjects($objects,['createIfNotExists' => true ]);  line work fine according to my question thank,s once again